# Invertir contenido de cadena en C#

Tags: c#

Me han pedido que haga un programa que pida al usuario una cadena y que el programa *la invierta* e imprima carácter a carácter de la cadena 4 veces.

Aquí tenéis el error que me sale:

> File "", line 3, in **main** Failed example:
> printf 'Codelearn\n' | mono /tmp/program.exe

**Resultado esperado:**

> Insert text phrase: nnnn
>
> rrrr
>
> aaaa
>
> eeee
>
> llll
>
> eeee
>
> dddd
>
> oooo
>
> CCCC
>
> Press any key.

**Resultado obtenido:**

> (1)Unhandled Exception:
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0001e] in :0
> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside
> the bounds of the array. at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0001e] in :0

> Insert a text string: nnnn
>
> rrrr
>
> aaaa
>
> eeee
>
> llll
>
> eeee
>
> dddd
>
> oooo
>
> CCCC

**Código de la aplicación:**

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s;
        Console.Write("Insert a text string: ");
        s = Console.ReadLine();
        int i = s.Length - 1;
        while (i < s.Length)
        {
            string s1 = new string(s[i], 4);
            Console.WriteLine(s1);
            i = i - 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
    }
}
```

Comment: La condición `i < s.Length` va a ser siempre cierta porque empieza por `s.Length - 1` y va decreciendo hasta que al llegar a `-1` genere la excepción.

Comment: Piensa en lo que has escrito. En estos casos ayuda traducirlo al español "plano". Declaras una variable `i` igual a la longitud - 1 de tu string. Pongamos que esto es 20. Luego haces un bucle MIENTRAS `i` SEA **MENOR** que la longitud... si `i` valía 20, la longitud sin el -1 será 21... y lo que haces en tu bucle es restarle 1 a `i`, con lo cual a la siguiente valdrá 19, luego 18... Así hasta que vale -1 y te has salido, porque estás en un bucle infinito. Tu variable `i` **SIEMPRE** será menor a `s.Length`.

Answer (score 5):

La condición `i < s.Length` va a ser siempre cierta porque el valor de `i` empieza por `s.Length - 1` y va decreciendo hasta que al llegar a `-1` genera la excepción.

Deberías cambiar el bucle para que se ejecute mientras el valor de `i` sea 0 o superior:

```
while (i >= 0)
{
    string s1 = new string(s[i], 4);
    Console.WriteLine(s1);
    i = i - 1;
}
```

---

Otra manera de conseguir el mismo resultado sin hacer uso de bucles sería como muestro a continuación:

```
// Convertimos la cadena a una matriz de caracteres
char[] sArray = s.ToCharArray();
// Invertimos el orden de los elementos (caracteres) de la matriz
Array.Reverse(sArray);
// Imprimirmos el resultado repitiendo cada carácter en una línea separada
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        Array.ConvertAll(sArray, letra => new string(letra, 4))
    )
);
```

Para imprimir el resultado hemos iterado los elementos de la matriz con caracteres, generando una cadena de caracteres con la repetición solicitada y, por último, colocando una nueva línea entre cada carácter repetido 4 veces.

PD: Gracias a [Jose A. Fernandez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/557/jose-a-fernandez) por sugerir la primera parte de la mejora.

Comment: Perfecto, ya he solucionado el problema y lo he entendido perfectamente. ¡Gracias Oscar!

Answer (score 0):

Dejo otra forma de realizar ayudanonos con el metodo [Reverse de la clase Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-7.0) que invierte el orden de los elementos. Asi que se transforma el string (que internamente a array con luego se invierte)

Para repetir la cada caracters se utiliza previamente el metodo [Array.ConvertAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=net-7.0) que recibe una "funcion" de conversion, que ahora lo utilizamos para crear por cada caracter, el mismo pero repetido x veces.

Dejo el ejemplo para ejecutarlo aquí online https://dotnetfiddle.net/e5POPQ

```
    var phrase = "The force is strong with you";
    
    //Repetir X veces cada caracter de la frase
    var phraseWithLetterRepeat = String.Join(string.Empty, Array.ConvertAll(phrase.ToCharArray(), letra => new string(letra, 4)));
    
    //Convertir a array de char para poder realizar Array.Reverse
    var phraseArray  = phraseWithLetterRepeat.ToCharArray();
        
    Console.WriteLine(phrase);      
    Console.WriteLine(phraseArray); 
    
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-6.0
    Array.Reverse(phraseArray);       
    
    Console.WriteLine(phraseArray);
```

Se agrego la parte faltante de repetir cada "caracter" x veces antes de revertir el orden de la cadena (gracias el comentario de [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia)

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea válida deberías resolver la segunda parte del problema: "imprima carácter a carácter de la cadena 4 veces". Al final habría que iterar `phraseArray` o bien usar algo como `string.Join("", Array.ConvertAll(phraseArray, letra => new string(letra, 4)));`.

Comment: Muy bueno @OscarGarcia y simple! Edito la respuesta para que quede completa con tu aporte